# read_html not pulling info from tables

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to gather the locations for the documents found on the SEC website. When I use the read_html() function, the table function is returning empty sets and I'm not sure why.  When I inspect the elements using my web browser, I can see that the nodes in  are populated but that information is not being carried over into my session.

```
test_url <- "https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/dateRange=custom&entityName=(CIK%25200000887568)&startdt=1980-01-01&enddt=2021-06-23&filter_forms=10-K"

pg <- read_html(test_url) %>% 
   html_nodes(., css="#hits > table") 


#But its empty
xml_attrs(pg, xml_child(pg[[1]], 2))
[[1]]
  class 
"table"
```

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Forgot to add that the html code is populated online (which makes sense because its a published webpage). <tr><td class="filetype"><a href="#d221219d10ka.htm" class="preview-file" data-adsh="0001193125-11-327240" data-file-name="d221219d10ka.htm">10-K/A (Annual report) </a></td><td class="filed">2011-12-01</td><td class="enddate">2011-10-02</td><td class="entity-name">ZOLL MEDICAL CORP </td><td class="cik d-none" nowrap="">CIK 0000887568</td><td class="biz-location located d-none" nowrap="">Chelmsford, MA</td> ...

Comment: Note that most webpages use javascript to load data. `read_html` cannot execute javascript for you. `read_html` can only see what is available if you click "view page source" on the web page or what's under the "Sources" tab in the developer tools. That can be very different than what's shown in the "Elements" tab. If you need to access a site that uses javascript, you'll need something like RSelenium to help. Alternativly you can reverse engineer the site to try to figure out where the data is coming from

Comment: Yep, what @MrFlick said. There are a lot of good tutorials showing how to examine the underlying data streams and intercept them, including the one I wrote at https://iqss.github.io/dss-workshops/PythonWebScrape.html. It uses Python but the concepts are the same in R. I recommend this approach over Selenium when possible.